# List of strings from java to html to jquery using data attributes

Tags: java, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to display dynamically some data from the server side (struts java)  using jquery datatable, first I tried to hard code my data testing in a jsfidle, thing works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/c918of3t/35/

```
<td class="details-control" data-agencies='["agency22", "agency33","agency17","agency89"]'></td>
```

when you click in the green plus icon you will see the detail data coming from data attributes, but when I try it dynamically:

http://s4.postimg.org/8d7ki80q5/rr2.png

it does not work.

Comment: You'll want to share your code. I'm guessing you've got something like `<%= someValue %>` where you should have `<%= SomeUtil.json(someValue) %>`

Comment: What he said--obviously something is different between the dynamic, browser rendered version, and your hard coded version. Use the web inspector to see what's getting rendered where you're expecting the array.

Comment: server side send this string jsonAgencies = ["AAAWRGH","Acceptance Test Agency"] , but when inspection I got this error :           Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '21' in ["AAAWRGH","Acceptance

Comment: I am using gson api to sent that string, it wraps the  string that contains double quotes in double quotes, that is the problem, but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: the view source shows :           <td class="details-control" data-agencies=[&quot;AAAWRGH&quot;,&quot;Acceptance Test Agency&quot;]></td>

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I just added single quotes around my property bean in my jsp :

```
<td class="details-control" data-agencies='<bean:write name="rrag" property="agencies" />'></td>
```